# C++: Vector of fixed but runtime defined length arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I know that I can use

`std::vector<std::array<int, 20> > myVec;`

as a container for a matrix growable in single dimension. However `std:array<>` size has to be defined in compile time. Is there any simple way how to do the same for runtime defined arrays?

I need this for processing several GB of data so I'm affraid that vector of vectors would bring in unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Would `std::vector<std::vector<int> > myVec;` work for you?

Comment: Are both dimensions fixed? If so, use a M*N sized vector (or wrap one up on a matrix-like class.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I need this for processing several GB of data so I'm affraid that
>   vector of vectors would bring in unnecessary overhead.

Then write a wrapper class around a one dimensional `vector` which allows two-dimensional indexing, and give the one fixed dimension as a constructor-argument.

That is the most efficient way, since there is only one level of indirection.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider using `std::vector< std::vector<int> >` to hold your data. Premature optimization is not a good thing to do.

If it is too slow, you can write your own or use a third-party memory allocator for that `vector`. Custom memory allocators could be significantly faster for specific aims like yours (storing many objects of the same size).

The idea of Loopunroller of using wrapper around `std::vector<int>` is nice too.

Comment: I agree and if you don't want the vector to hold more than a set size use [std::vector::resize](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/)

Comment: Watch out when using resize, because it removes elements when your requested size is smaller than the vector currently holds

Comment: A vector of vectors would only make sense inside a wrapper class, because there is nothing to guarantee that the inner vectors have the same length. That invariant has to be enforced somehow.

Comment: @risingDarkness very true, but in this case I'm presuming the OP knows how large he wants the vector.